# Airflow DAG scheduled with a day late but manual triggers is not

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I use **Airflow 1.8.0** 
and I have a DAG like this one :

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['technical@me.com'],
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 21),
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}


dag = DAG('my_dag',
          schedule_interval='40 20 * * *',
          catchup=True,
          default_args=default_args)
```

Every day the dag is correctly scheduled but with a day late.

Given today's date is

**2018-07-02**

the web interface show :

[image]

instead of **2018-07-01**

But if I do a manual trigger 
The current date is correctly passed :

[image]

Is there a way to force scheduler to run with the current date ?

Comment: Both dates are correct in Airflow speak. Manual triggers take the current time. Schedules are run *when the timebox is over*: "The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.". See more in the Airflow docs: https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html

Comment: Okay thank you, so I can't force Airflow to run before the timebox is over ?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. You can use another date like tomorrow, though, see Airflow macros: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct and is a part of the design of airflow. If you look [here](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html) you'll see the explanation:

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.
>
> **Let’s Repeat That** The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Answer (score 0):

Your `schedule_interval` is `schedule_interval='20 40 * * *'`. Remember that the `schedule_interval` is in CRON format, or (Minutes Hour Day(month) Month day(week). So your current schedule is actually incorrect as the scheduler **cannot** run every 40th hour. Do you want to make it so that it runs at the 40th minute every 20 hours? If so, try `schedule_interval='40 20 * * *'`.

Also, set `catchup` to `catchup=False` if you want it to run the most recent day. With both of these fixes, it should work. Refer to this website for more [CRON](https://crontab.guru/) help.

Comment: I already tried with `catchup=False` (in fact I started the job with the parameter)
I think `catchup=True` is used to specify airflow to create the missing DAG between now and the last successful DAG run

Comment: Hey @RonanT - check my most recent revision. It seems your schedule interval is a little off too. Your assumption about the catchup is accurate as well, but I always prefer to make it as `false` so that it runs the most recent day. You can always create duplicate manual trigger dags to backfill the days you missed using `start_date` and `end_date`.